# Importing server public key into FileZilla (or other sftp clients)

Tags: ssh, sftp, filezilla, public-key

## How to import server public key into FileZilla?

I'm able to access my server from SSH, and have the privilege to view whatever that's in `/etc/ssh`. I can produce hash fingerprints for these public keys.

But is there a button in FileZilla that actually allow me to import those server authentication credentials? Or do I have to do "Trust-On-First-Use" for my server?

## To avoid certain type of XY problem:

Due to 2019-nCoV, some of our collegues had to work at home, so I'm writing a guide for them to download necessary files. I chosed FileZilla because it's cross platform. WinSCP seems to be able to import those public keys, but it's Windows-specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FileZilla does not have such function.

You would have to import the keys manually into the cache. FileZilla uses a customized version of PuTTY psftp under the hood. So it uses PuTTY host key cache. On Windows it's in Windows Registry under `HKCU\Software\SimonTatham\PuTTY\SshHostKeys`. Actually WinSCP can export the host key to PuTTY (and FileZilla) cache. But that won't help you with other OSes.

Comment: Got it. Hope to see FZ team add this feature to refute this answer. I'll be looking at alternatives. Cheers.